# Why is there a strict inequality in the independent increments condition of a Brownian motion?

Tags: brownian-motion, independence

The Brownian motion $\{W_t: t \geq 0\}$ satisfies the independent increment property:

If $0 \leq t_0 < t_1 <\dots < t_n$, then
$$W_{t_0}, W_{t_1}-W_{t_0}, \dots, W_{t_n}-W_{t_{n-1}}$$

are independent.

Why is there a strict inequality in the $0 \leq t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n$?

If $t_i \leq t_{i+1}$ for some $i$, then we just have

$$W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i} = 0$$
which will not affect the independency, as a constant random variable is independent from all other random variables.

What am I missing?

Comment: An increment over the time period $(t_i,t_{i+1})$ is uninteresting if $t_{i+1}-t_i=0$.

Comment: But mathematically it is correct to include $\leq$ instead of $<$?

Comment: For Brownian Motion, yes. If you allow for jumps, I think it might go wrong, because if the endpoint of one interval equals the startpoint of the other (which would be possible then) and a jump occurs at exactly this point (it would need not to be a nullset), then one can get interdependence. But for BM this is obviously no topic so I always assumed that it only is notation. Maybe to be ellegant, maybe to make more clear that it also is a Levy process.

Comment: An increment is defined to be non-zero.

Comment: Bhattacharya, **Stochastic Processes with Applications,** and Billingsley, **Probabiility and Measure**, but use strict inequalities in their definitions.